# Single line TabPanel & button to show hidden tabs

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I am having a tab control where the requirement is to have a single TabPanel and also have a button at the top right to show the hidden tabs.

I found one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219863/tabcontrol-with-single-line-tabpanel-and-overflow-panel) .

As per the solution mentioned in this link, I updated the template and replaced the TabPanel with a ToolBar. This works fine for me.

But there is one problem. The tabs are not responding on click. If I click any of the tabs it does not get activated. I assume only updating the template is not all. May be I have to write some code to handle the click on the toolbar. Here is my xaml code

```
<Window.Resources>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Background" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Border" Color="#ACACAC"/>
    <Style x:Key="TabControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--<TabPanel x:Name="headerPanel" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>-->

                        <ToolBar x:Name="headerPanel" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Items}"/>
                        <Border x:Name="contentPanel" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,0,2,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,2,0,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0,2,2,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="tabData" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <sys:String>MyTab1</sys:String>
            <sys:String>MyTab2</sys:String>                
        </x:Array>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource tabData}" Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle1}">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=Items.Count}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>        
</Grid>
```

Can somebody please help...

Thanks

Comment: Share your code here so that we can see how you are using the template.

Comment: Code is added...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not working because your ToolBar's ItemsSource is resolving to the 'tabData' string array, instead of resolving to the TabItems.

If you make this slight change, it works:

```
    <Grid>
        <!--<Grid.Resources>
            <x:Array x:Key="tabData" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
                <sys:String>MyTab1</sys:String>
                <sys:String>MyTab2</sys:String>
            </x:Array>
        </Grid.Resources>-->
        <!--<TabControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource tabData}" Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle1}">-->
        <TabControl Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle1}">
            <TabItem Header="MyTab1">Content of Tab 1</TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="MyTab2">Content of Tab 2</TabItem>
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=Items.Count}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```